# Page prec with leaflet

Tags: leaflet

If I go on [the leaflet site](http://leafletjs.com/), and zoom the map, then I go on another site, then I return on the leaflet site with "page prec" on the browser, I get the map with no zoom.

How is it possible to build a leaflet map with the same state after a page prec ?

Answer (score 1):

This plug-in for Leaflet handles a permalink which will do the job for you

https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can add handlers to `moveend` and `zoomend` map events and store curent position and zoom to `localstorage` or on server or url hash. On map load you can get position and zoom from this storageis.

You also can add js object as buffers and timer to avoid slow performance on active map move and zoom usage.

If you want restore only on back button click you must detect how page loaded. I found next question: [How to detect that user open page using BACK button in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312953/how-to-detect-that-user-open-page-using-back-button-in-browser) but it's so old.